# Undefined reference to when including file from separate directory

Tags: qt, include, compiler-errors

I have very basic QT application (just create to explain my problem).
So here I go :) I have two folders, f1 and f2, and they are on same level (have same folder for parent). In f1 I have source code from my project, and in f2 another project.
For sake of this example, let's say that in f1 I have only common.h and common.cpp, and in f2 I have:

Test.pro

```
SOURCES = main.cpp
INCLUDEPATH += "..//f1//"
```

main.cpp

```
#include <common.h>
#include <QDebug>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    qDebug()<<CalculateMD5("test");
}
```

When I try to build this project (Test.pro) I get following error:
f2/main.cpp:7: undefined reference to `CalculateMD5(QString)'

What am I doing wrong ? How should I include code from another project ?
I need CalculateMD5 function to be global.

Here you can download whole example (1kb):
http://www.xx77abs.com/test.rar

Thanks !!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the simplest change, I think you need to change your .pro file to this:

Test.pro

```
SOURCES = main.cpp ../f1/common.cpp
INCLUDEPATH += "..//f1//"
```

If you have other code that will also be linking in common.cpp, then a better change would be to make a .pro file in f1 that generates a library, to be linked in to other applications.

But just manually adding common.cpp to your list of sources should do the trick.

Comment: I'm also not sure why you've got double-slashes in your `INCLUDEPATH` - I expect that `"../f1"` would work too

Comment: Thanks ! I was just experimenting with path to see if it's the problem ("\\f1" also works ;)) But I am using "../f1". Thanks again !!

Comment: I'm sorry for removing this answer as accepted, but I have another problem and don't want to create new question for it (it is related to this one). I've edited my question, could you take a look at it ?

Comment: But I did actually answer your question!